# Nvidia graphic cards not detected after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I have an NVIDIA GeForce 1080 Ti working fine on Ubuntu 16.04.

After a power outage a couple days ago, it stopped working: `nvidia-smi` not working and GPU not found in `lspci`/`lsmod`. After rebooting the machine a couple of times and shutting off for a couple of hours, it worked again out of nowhere.

I reboot the machine today and I have the same issue: `nvidia-smi` not working and GPU not found in `lspci`/`lsmod`/`lshw`. I tried to re-install the drivers 384 and 390, to install `nvidia-modprobe`, update pciids, but it doesn't work either.

The output of `lspci -nn | grep '\[03'` is :
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 [8086:5912] (rev 04)`

Thank you very much for any help !

Comment: could try to check for conflicting pci issues in bios if your machine supports it..also making sure no other generic "Graphics Card Drivers" have decided to turn on since the last power outage which could be causing conflict.

Comment: Yes, I can access to the Asus BIOS but I didn't find where I can change the graphics card settings. How can I turn off this potentially graphics cards driver causing conflict?

Comment: In a Linux based system, i'm not sure how you would check out hardware/driver information. In windows you can just do it in the device manager. I would suggest looking for a resource in regards to how to do so in Linux. In bios it could be under hardware and you should see some different options. I'm not sure if you will see anything in reference to the issues you are having but it doesn't hurt to look!

Comment: I have a Graphics Configuration setting, but the only parameters are Primary Display (CPU Graphics or Auto), iGPU Multi Monitor (Enable/Disable), RC6 (Enable/Disable) and DVT Pre-Allocated (Mb). Do you know if it's one of these parameters? Thanks !!

Comment: I would look at the option regarding Primary Display and see if that changes when you notice your "preferred" graphics card stops working. maybe there is some sort of fail-over method at play here that is setup in those settings! Without actually having the software in front of me though that's probably the best advice I could give! I hope this helps!

Comment: Initially, it was set to CPU Graphics, I changed it to PCI, but it has no effect on `lspci`. However, when I recheck the BIOS, it's set to auto. It goes back to auto every time I set it to PCIE, and no eventual effect. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi again Attia, I think you may be on to something. I had a suspicion that this could be the possible culprit. see if there is any way you can force the option to use cpu graphics to stay on no matter what!

Comment: I am trying but I don't know how, I have tested the different possible options of `Graphics Configuration` and I cannot access to it out of BIOS. I am thinking about re-installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened the machine and remove the dust inside and it seems to work now.
I don't know if it's possible that the dust was the culprit but for now, it works!